# Windows Phone Text to speech

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, text-to-speech

i am trying to use a WP speech library i got from codeplex, now the code is fine with no errors, but there are no voice output!!

```
using wpSpeech;


namespace TalkForMe
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           SpeechTTS spk;
           spk = new SpeechTTS ( textBox1.Text);
           spk.SpeakLanguage = "en";
           spk.SpeakText(textBox1.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a very small mistake. You created a reference for SpeakTTS but didn't allocate any memory for it. try like this and try.

```
SpeechTTS spk=new SpeakTTS();
```

Comment: it says Error 1 The type or namespace name 'SpeakTTS' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Thair\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TalkForMe\TalkForMe\MainPage.xaml.cs 30 31 TalkForMe

Comment: Did you add the reference for sdk for speech to text? Btw if you were to create a reference for speechtts, then why can't you instantiate it  ??