# How to register my application for text to speech in windows phone 7 in bing.com?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

My requirement is text to speech in windows phone 7. So I search in google and I           find out the link and I try to register in bing.com/developers page but its going some where

I have tried with this webpage link but its going to windows azure page.

http://www.bing.com/developers/appids.aspx

and I have followed this tutorial.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/259727/Text-to-speech-in-windows-phone7

Or else please suggest me any useful link for this problem.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I noticed the Bing API moved to Azure, myself.  Doing a few searches came [up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15720658/windows-phone-text-to-speech) [with](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/hawaii/default.aspx) [these](https://www.ispeech.org/developers/dotnet) [possible](http://ttsforwindowsphone7.codeplex.com/) [options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dd901770).  I haven't tested any of them, but I'm working on adding similar functionality to my app.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled upon this question. Its quite old but I don't think you need Bing. The Bing speech controls are something I would use for speech to text, but you said you wanted text to speech. That can be accomplished quite easily on the Windows phone by using the SpeechSynthesizer. Please see this tutorial here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207057(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Note that the question title specifies Windows Phone 7 and that link specifies Windows Phone 8.  It may not be of any help.

Answer (score 0):

I just added simple text-to-speech capabilities to [my Windows Phone 7 app](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=013fb625-cce4-4bc4-a577-1a183073a644) (well, the beta version) using [Text-To-Speech with Microsoft Translator Service](http://translatorservice.codeplex.com/).

You can download it from their site, [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/translatorservice.speech), or from within Visual Studio (that's how I found it - Manage NuGet Packages - search for "Text-To-Speech").

Here's some C# code to get started...

```
// required for SpeechSynthesizer
using TranslatorService.Speech;

namespace AppName
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        private void TextToSpeech_Play(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SpeechSynthesizer speech = new SpeechSynthesizer(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);
            speech.SpeakAsync("This is a beautiful day!");
        }
    }
}
```

To use this library, you need to go to  [Azure DataMarket](https://datamarket.azure.com/developer/applications) and register your application to obtain the Client ID and Client Secret that are necessary to use the service. You also need to go to  https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/1899a118-d202-492c-aa16-ba21c33c06cb and subscribe the Microsoft Translator Service. There are many options, based on the amount of characters per month. The service is free up to 2 million characters per month.